# Problems making a distribution for the raspberry using buildroot

Tags: boot-issues, qemu, buildroot

I'm trying to use buildroot to build a minimalist distribution targeted to the raspberry pi. I'm following a guide that was provided to me in a class, in my university. During that class I followed the guide and I managed to build the system and run it in QEMU and in a raspberry pi 3, but now and I'm trying to do it again,  at home, following the same guide, with my own raspberry. The SD card has 2 partitions the first one has a VFAT file system with the firmware (bootloader and kernel files), that according to the guide is provided by "raspberry pi developers" but I downloaded the file from my university's server. The second partition is a ext4 file system which contains the root file system created by the buildroot.
After making all this I managed to run it perfectly in QEMU using the second partition of the SD card with the following command:

```
qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -append "root=/dev/sda console=serial0" -hda /dev/sdd2
```

where sdd is the SD card.
But when I put the SD card in the raspberry it doesn't work properly. It shows 4 raspberry logos, when it should only be 1, and then nothing happens. It should show the welcome banner and the root login prompt.
For me it seems the problem is in the first partition but I can't find any problem and since I followed the same guide that I did previously....
Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

The `cmdline.txt` file looks like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Comment: Which model Pi are you using at home?

Comment: raspberry pi 3 model B and at university I believe it is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing the root parameter in the cmdline.txt to:

root=/dev/mmcblk0p2